# Как правильно использовать одну переменную в двух js файлах?

Tags: javascript

есть два js файла. В одном из файлов объявляется переменная. И я хочу использовать эту переменную во втором js файле, с тем значением которое присвоил этой переменной в первом файле. Как это правильно сделать?

Comment: Можно в корневом html файле подключить эти 2 скрипта, скрипт с переменной должен подключаться первее

Comment: иногда чтобы не протаскивать что-то через райские кущи, можно воспользоваться системой событий или общей точкой синхронизации, но это вкусовщина

Answer (score 4):

**В случае, если нужно read-only значение:**

`export let example1 = ...`

Во втором файле пишете:

`import {example1} from "./1stJSfile.js";`

**Если нужна возможность менять значение:**
Тогда обращаемся к методу работы любого фреймворка - переводим *ВСЕ* в объекты.

```
export let example1 = {
   data: "11",
   change: function(prop) {
     this.data = prop;
   },
 };
```

Во второй файл импортим объект и оперируем его методами:

```
import {example1} from "./1st.js";

 example1.change("22");

 document.getElementById("app").innerHTML =
 `<div>
 ${example1.data}
</div>`;
```

Comment: а при инициализации переменной таким методом, можно её использовать в файле в котором её обновляешь?

Comment: @Aleks по 1 способу можно переназначать только в том файле, где переменная инициирована. В других файлах значение "только для чтения".
2 способом можно переназначать значение в любом файле

Answer (score 0):

По этой статье https://learn.javascript.ru/import-export можно импортировать и сразу экспортировать так:

```
//  auth/index.js

// импортировать login/logout и тут же экспортировать
import {login, logout} from './helpers.js';
export {login, logout};

// импортировать экспорт по умолчанию как User и тут же экспортировать
import User from './user.js';
export {User};
...
```