# JAVASCRIPT/ Kotlin Состояние переменной

Tags: kotlin

Есть класс студент, на основе которого строится массив студентов в отдельном файле. 
В другом файле происходит сортировка массива, в которой происходит очищение состояния массива функцией clear

Есть функция окрашивания конкретного студента которая выполняется до того как выполнена сортировка.

Вопрос:

> как сохранить состояние студента (то что он поменял цвет с черного на
>   розовый) что бы после сортировки его цвет сохранялся?

На рисунке один файл students, на рисунке два файл main в котором есть ещё функция сортировки в которой происходит очищение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1088030/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-js-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85)

Вам необходимо создать в каждом объекте метод регулирования цветом, т.е. функцию, к которой вы будете обращаться для смены состояния цвета и менять цвет перед тем как кидать объект в массив.

**Основная идея в том, чтобы вы где-то хранили значение цвета. В моем примере - это elDOM, который хранит вообще целый элемент дома.**

```js
let students = [];

class Student {

  constructor(firstname, surename, presence) {
   this.firstname = firstname;
   this.surename = surename;
   this.presence = presence;
   this.elDOM = null;
 }
 
  putIntoPage() {
   this.elDOM = document.createElement('div');
   this.elDOM.innerHTML = `<p> ${this.firstname} ${this.surename} </p>`;
   document.body.append(this.elDOM);
 }
 
  colorify() {
   if (this.presence === true) {
     this.elDOM.style.color = "grey";
     this.presence = false;
   } else {
     this.elDOM.style.color = "white";
     this.presence = true;
   }
  }
};

let student = new Student("masha", "avoska", true);

student.putIntoPage();
student.colorify();
students.push(student);

console.log(students);
```

Comment: Получается добавить то что вы написали даже если класс сделан так: data class Students (firstname:string,  surname:string, pris: Boolean)

Comment: И сам массив выглядит так val a = arrayof ( Students ("anna","ivanova","true")

Comment: Переменная pris участвует в смене цвета в другом файле в функции

Comment: 1) есть класс с состояниями
2) есть функция, которая читает состояния, и добавляет еще одно состояние Цвет
3) есть массив объектов, в которых уже после функции есть состояние Цвет
<br />
я правильно все понимаю?

Comment: Исправила вопрос, добавила как выглядит код. Да есть класс в котором записаны имена и состояние, также есть функция ,насчёт третьего не уверена

Comment: @Bluecookies исправил. Разница между JS и Котлин все же довольно велика :)

Comment: Спасибо,попробую реализовать, получается это в том файле где класс, а в файле где основная функция ничего не нужно менять?

Comment: @Bluecookies в основной функции вы пытаетесь обратиться к элементу ДОМа по id, который равен имени студента. Я может не знаю каких-то очень магических техник Котлина, но выглядит как то, что в целом не будет работать так как вы хотели бы. Так что да, лучше реализоват смену цвета по методу в классе.

Comment: И получается больше код ориентирован на js?

Comment: @Bluecookies код ориентирован под ООП, а оно везде почти одинаковое для объектно-ориентированных языков.
Структура: `создаем класс -> конструктор по имени, фамилии, пресенсу -> создаем метод вывода класса на страницу -> создаем метод, который по пресенсу влияет на метод вывода класса на страницу` а далее вне класса уже делаем с ним то, что хотим